# jQuery app problem. Is this a glitch or incorrect coding?

Tags: jquery, transition

I've got into a rather simple, yet annoying problem.

I'm trying to create a kind of "pick a date" calendar, but in carousel style, just like those image sliders.

Once the user clicks on a date, the `<div>` should scroll to the center, and have its CSS changed, animated.

I've found this image slider which is exactly what I need: http://opiefoto.com/articles/photoslider (**Demo at the bottom**)

All I wanted to do, is, take off the big image and the play / pause button, and change the CSS a little bit, so far, I've managed to do THIS: http://chadascinco.net/photoslider/

People with keen eye for glitches probably already had noticed that... when you click on a thumbnail, and then click on another, the previous one **keeps its old height**, still, you can see it "flicking" like something is forcing it back to that height.

And that's my problem.

If you check using firebug or something similar, you'll notice that the height GOES to 66px, but goes back to 121px just after that.

And now, for something weird, if I take off the "top" value change, the height works perfectly. It grows and go back exactly as I need. But if I put it back... damn, there we go, height glitch.

I've tried to contact the author through email, but it has been 3 days and I've gotten no reply back.

And here I ask ya all for a share of knowledge, I'm a very newcomer with JavaScript and jQuery, so it might be also a problem in my code. I just tried to use basic programming logic.

The js responsible is "photoslider.js" and if you check for "FELIX Note", you'll find notes in every single part where i made any changes. Any other comments are original from the author.

The lines where the transition works are from 265 to 287.

If anything I said is confusing, I'd be glad to be more accurate.

If you guys also need to check the original code, you can check it here: http://chadascinco.net/photoslideroriginal

Also, if you know any other application that works like what I need, I'd be most thankful to know.

Thank you all once again.

**BRAND NEWS EDIT**: I've found one interesting fact: if you check the lines i mentioned, you'll notice 3 animation calls.

No matter what you do, if you put the same CSS property on the **SECOND** call for both active and inactive divs, it'll flick and cause this glitch. I've tried changed to "background-color" instead of height, changing from black to white and backwards.

Here's what happened: When i load the page, only the active one is black. Good. But when i click another, this one becomes black, and the **PREVIOUS** one tries to become white, but is forced to become black again. i wonder, why only the Second call? If it was the first, or the last, or every of them, alright, but... only the second? Weird.

Comment: +1 for a question like this, it's great for the community to come together to solve an issue like this.

Comment: I have heard that not having the correct doctype can cause animation flicker's, try changing the doctype to html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, I got the problem. The thing is this library isn't expecting you to use multiple animations at a time. the function SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.animate which inits the animations creates a field in the animated object, called skel_animate_id, which is in fact the id of a timer set up to do the animation.

As this library doesn't expect multiple animations at a time, when you create a new animation, it just does `element.skel_animate_id = setInterval(.....`, and if you are following me, you'll realize that anything that was on `skel_aimate_id` before (i.e. the library's only reference to any previous animation's timers) is lost after that assignment.

Now, there's a step function, called by the timers, which is in charge of recognizing when the animation has ended, and stop the timer itself, but it does that by calling `clearInterval(element.skel_animate_id);`, which will obviously only clear the timer related to the last attribute animated.

Long story short, when you call the second attribute's animation (before the first one ended), you leave an open timer, which keeps on going and going "animating" the first attribute (i.e. setting it to it's final value).

**EDIT:** [Live demo of fix.](http://jsfiddle.net/FcFzc/)

**THE GUILTY SNIPPET**

Lines [488-531]

```
SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide = {
counter: 0,
fps: 50,

//handles the animation from an attribute to an attribute
animate: function(element,cssAttribute,from,to,duration,transition){

    if(element.css('display') != 'block'){
        element.skel_old_display = element.css('display');
    }

    //if there isn't a default transition set one
    if(!transition){
        transition = SKEL.Transitions.quadOut;
    }

    //cancel any current animation

    // FELIX Note: I've commented this because when we had 3 transitions on the same element, this function would make only the first one to work.
    //SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.stop(element);

    var startTime = new Date().getTime();

    //IE doesn't support arguments, so make a function that explicitly calls with those arguments
    element.skel_animate_id = setInterval(function(){
        SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.step(element,cssAttribute,from,to,duration,startTime,transition);
    },(1000/SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.fps));

    return element.skel_animate_id;
},

//cancels any animation event
stop: function(element){
    //console.log(this,element,element.skel_animate_id);
    //console.log(element.skel_animate_id);
    if(element.skel_animate_id){
        clearInterval(element.skel_animate_id);
        element.skel_animate_id = 0;
        if(element.skel_old_display){
            element.css('display',element.skel_old_display);
        }
    }

},
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I'd have `skel_animate_ids` as an array, and store every interval with a reference to the attribute animated, so the step function nows which interval to clear.

in SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.animate

```
if (!element.skel_animate_ids){
    element.skel_animate_ids = new Object();
}

//IE doesn't support arguments, so make a function that explicitly calls with those arguments
element.skel_animate_ids[cssAttribute] = setInterval(function(){
            SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.step(element,cssAttribute,from,to,duration,startTime,transition);
        },(1000/SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.fps));

return element.skel_animate_ids[cssAttribute];
```

then in SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.stop

```
//cancels any animation event
stop: function(element,attribute){
    if(element.skel_animate_ids[attribute]){
        clearInterval(element.skel_animate_ids[attribute]);
        delete element.skel_animate_ids[attribute];
        if(element.skel_old_display){
            element.css('display',element.skel_old_display);
        }
    }

},
```

and in SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.step (line 575)

```
if(finished){
    SKEL.EFFECTS.Slide.stop(element,cssAttribute);
}
```

I think that should do it, but I can't really test it in my browser. If my code doesn't quite work, I must have missed something, but I'm still sure that's the problem, you just have to figure out how to solve it (or change libraries =D). You just try my suggestion, let me know how it worked.

Cheers

**EDIT:** I couldn't wait, so I whipped a JSFiddle to test, and yeah, it works with those changes. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/FcFzc/).

**EDIT2:** Corrected typo: was still referencing skel_animate_id instead of skel_animate_ids in the first bit of code.

Comment: Wow, that was very neat! Now i understand where i was doing wrong, yeah, it makes total sense. I'm gonna test this when i get to work, and really thanks for pointing all that explanation.

Comment: @Tio Hey, I had an error in the code for the proposed solution. Already fixed it in my answer: you should always be working with skel_animate_ids now instead of skel_animate_id (I had left one skel_animate_id in the first bit of code).

Comment: i noticed that, don't worry. :) Already fixed on my code. Thank you very much for this solution, bro. I wish someday i'll be able to know as much as you guys here, so i could help other people too. Marked as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your haste to remove functionality from the slider, you basically butchered it, if you can pardon my language:

```
/* var sliderCaption = $(document.createElement('div'));
sliderCaption.addClass('photoslider_caption');

sliderDiv.append(sliderCaption);

var sliderNav = $('#'+key+' .photoslider_nav').get(0);
if(sliderNav != null){
     //remove it
     $(sliderNav).remove();
} */

sliderNav = $(document.createElement('div'));
sliderNav.addClass('photoslider_nav');
```

The syntax highlighter should already tell you what's wrong.You commented out the definition for a critical variable in the application's design.

Try at the very least, letting everything connected to the `sliderNav` variable there. That is the functionality you are trying to mimic.

Comment: Sorry man, but I don't think you make any sense, he didn't really need to comment out the sliderNav part, but that doesn't affect the script. That bit was (I think) related to trying to reset the slider or something like that, it just removes any existing .photoslider_nav so it can create a new one. He is still creating a new one after that comment block, so there should be no problem.
If you take a closer look, what you posted is inside the reload function, and it starts like this:  //loads in the slideshow, replaces the existing one if set
    reload: function(key){.....

Comment: @jcane86 Which is mildly consistent with his second scenario. I was merely trying to point out he is cutting out important pieces of the code. The original framework, with css to hide the main image and to enlarge the nav area [works](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/rsksg/). This can only mean he deleted critical portions of the code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the case. If you read my answer, he is just misusing the library. I might be wrong, because I wasn't able to test it, but I'm almost positive that was the issue

Comment: Yeah, i agree i had some haste, probably because of my newbness when it comes to javascript and similars. Thanks for point that out, now that i think about it, yeah, kinda dumb of my part. Thank you :D